# Length of wire to calculate its power losses

Tags: power, dc, wire, 12v, loss

Let us say I have 12V DC battery and I am using 10m long wire to connect my load with it. Now if I want to calculate power losses in the wire then should I use wire length as 10m or 20m (since there are 2 wires + and - each of 10m in length)?

Comment: Search AWG tables. Its just Ohms Law

Comment: same current flows in each of the two wires ... each of the two wires has the same resistance ... each of the two wires will produce the same voltage drop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to consider both the supply and return line losses when calculating the total. You’d determine that from your wire unit resistance (ohms/m), multiply that by distance, and double it to get each direction’s resistance losses to get the total.